# Where to install catkin_ws for DJI Onboard-SDK ROS

Tags: ros, dji-sdk, catkin

I’m trying to set up a ROS install using the instructions found here:

http://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/sample-doc/sample-setup.html#ros-oes

Specifically I am happy and things install and make successfully until I reach step 4:

```
Building the ROS Nodes
4. If you don't have a catkin workspace, create one as follows:
mkdir catkin_ws
cd catkin_ws
mkdir src
cd src
catkin_init_workspace
```

Where does this catkin_ws go? In the previous step we are in ~MyUser/Onboard-SDK/build/ but this doesn’t seem to be the right location to install the catkin_ws?
As of now I’ve attempted an install the catkin_ws inside the build folder of ~MyUser/Onboard-SDK/build/catkin_ws which gave an error after step 6:

```
6. Build the dji_sdk ROS package and the dji_sdk_demo ROS package.
cd ..
catkin_make
```

Error:

```
"/home/sixarms/Onboard-SDK/build/catkin_ws/src/Onboard-SDK-
ROS/dji_sdk/include/dji_sdk/dji_sdk_node.h:17:19: fatal error: tf/tf.h: 
No such file or directory”
```

I then deleted everything inside MyUser/ folder and started again, this time I made a catkin_ws in the same folder as the OnBoard-SDK (i.e. ~MyUser/catkin_with with MyUser/OnBoard-SDK in the same folder) and I still get a fatal error on step 6, exactly the same. Can not find tf/tf.h. hmmm :/

Answer (score 0):

`catkin_ws` or any other name you give to it can go anywhere, different ros packages or dji_sdks or any other sdks then go inside `catkin_ws/src/`.

After step 4. (creating the workspace and initializing it) you should clone the dji_sdk package inside that `catkin_ws` at `catkin_ws/src/` source the setup.bash script `$ . devel/setup.bash` from within `catkin_ws/` and run `$ catkin_make` again from within `catkin_ws/`.

Comment: I built the catkin_ws and put both libraries dji_sdk and Onboard-SDKROS into the src folder. 
Same errors when using catkin make, certain files cannot be found, fatal error, etc etc after it reaches about 90% complete.

Thanks for clarifying about the catkin_ws, though it seems the instructions given by DJI are still incorrect or my particular case is broken.

Comment: Most likely you are missing some dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the solution for me was to install the full blown version of ROS instead of the base version:

`sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop`

Answer (score 0):

I know I have arrived quite late to the party but for anybody searching for this issue, most likely, this happens because there is a missing ROS library. If you install ROS full desktop version, probably won't have this problem. If you don't have a full desktop version, just run:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-<your_ros_version>-tf
```